# DynamoDB delete multiple items depending on value (Rust)

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS SDK in Rust. I want to delete multiple rows depending on a value that is not the partition or sort key.

I have a table with 3 columns:
id (number partition key),
namespace (string sort key),
age (number)

I want to delete every item from the table that has an age value of 10. I've heard of BatchWriteItem but haven't found a solution to deletion without using partition or sort key.

Comment: This will involve scanning the ENTIRE table and deleting the matching rows. Not sure there exist a different way than scanning plus filter expression, collecting the resulting items and then batch deleting them.

Comment: what would that look like? could it all be under one request?

Comment: Yes, you can delete multiple items (up to 25) in a single BatchWriteItem request, assuming you know the keys in advance, of course.

Comment: Also be aware of the native DynamoDB TTL feature. Probably not what you want but be aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete items you must always provide the primary key on DynamoDB, there is no alternative. That leaves you with two choices,

1. Create a GSI on `age` and Query the index for all items with age 10 efficiently. Use the result to pass into BatchWriteItem to delete the items.
2. If it's a relatively small amount of data or an infrequent Access pattern, then you can `Scan` the table and use a FilterExpression to return items with age=10… again passing the results onto BatchWriteItem to delete them.